Are transient buckets automatically deleted by Autodesk?
When created with "Transient" retention policy, the contents of a Autodesk/APS bucket will be automatically deleted after 24 hours. However, it seems the bucket itself (the container) is not deleted and remains empty. Is there a policy to use at bucket creation to automatically delete the bucket when empty after 24 hours?
I have a web service creating buckets with "Transient" retention policy used to perform a conversion with the Derivative API. The contents of the bucket is deleted as expected after 24 hours, but the buckets itself is not deleted. This is resulting with all the buckets created from past instances of the web service to accumulate, and I now have 100s of empty buckets. Each bucket has a unique name based on creation time+date, so there is not risk of conflict. I suspect having so many useless buckets will eventually hit the account performance. And at least, it makes manual maintenance or debugging of the account more difficult (e.g. when I need to handle a bucket created manually for debug).

The retention policy only concerne the objects stored inside the bucket. With a cronjob, you can easily automate this task on your web service : every day Get the list of all buckets > check the creation date / if there is object inside > Delete bucket

Buckets will not be deleted automatically, you have to delete them using this API, so uploading all the files to the same bucket with a timestamp or (UUID)Universal Unique Identifier is better.
You can prepend a meaningful text based on project or file type to both bucket and file names for easier search when needed.
Bucket policy documentation
